# How do I use a custom DOM node to render to from within a react component

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have the following problem:

I want to write `jsx` code like

```
<div className="my-section">
   <Window>
       <div>Window content</div>
   </Window>
</div>
<div className="window-container">
</div>
```

somewhere in my `react` content, but I want the window to render in a special `DOM` element with other windows, something like

```
<div class="my-section"></div>
<div class="window-container">
    <div class="window">
        <div>Window Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And to do this transparently I need to tell the component to render to a special `DOM` node from within the component. Is there a way to do this? If not, how should I accomplish the functionality I am looking for from within `React`?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the special `this.props.children` list.

> When you create a React component instance, you can include additional React components or JavaScript expressions between the opening and closing tags like this:
>
> ```
> <Parent><Child /></Parent>
> ```
>
> Parent can read its children by accessing the special this.props.children prop.

This will allow you to get the children defined inside your element, then insert them at an arbitrary point for render.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="window container">
      <div className="window">{this.props.children}</div>
      <div className="window"></div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I've been as clear as I could be - I'll update the question

Comment: I think this might be the answer I'm looking for, but I need to have some sort of global react element that scans it's children and pulls out the window instances, collects them together and puts them in the right place.